# What are the requirements for a device to support screen cast over Chromecast dongle

Tags: android, chromecast

This [link](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/2865484) lists the supported Android devices that can cast their screen over a Chromecast dongle onto a bigger display. Why aren't other devices like Moto X or E present on the list (both on version 4.4.4 as per the requirement) ? I observed that the "Cast screen" option appears under Settings -> Display on these devices. But it doesnt work.

Are there any hardware requirements for any device to support screen casting?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your issue solved? Please don't forget to accept the answer which helped you most.

Answer (score 1):

The Cast Screen feature is currently just in beta. Only a few select devices - like the Nexus 5 - are supported at this time, but this list will be expanded later on. Maybe at some point all Android devices will be supported.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this [link] (http://allaboutmotog.com/moto-g-wireless-display-the-problem-and-the-solution/) says that "Wireless display" is disabled in Moto G due to some hardware limitations. As per the docs of Screen casting via Chromecast, "Wireless display" setting should be checked for it to work.
    I didnt really understand what actually are the hardware limitations.

Comment: Hardware limitation is Moto G cannot cast and connect to internet through wifi at the same time. Its wifi can be used only for one purpose. But some other devices do not have this hardware limitation.

Answer (score 0):

Its all fake no need any hardware. Cast screen works by some system software module which might be missing. some devices gets updated with including cast screen function.